# Ошибка при запуске Java апплета macOS

Tags: java, mac, applet

При запуске апплета на macOS 10.13.6 (17G65), java 10.0.2 2018-07-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.2+13), выходит следующая ошибка:

> java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "modifyThreadGroup").

Апплет не мой, запускаю доп. материалы из книги: "Структуры данных и алгоритмы на Java", Р. Лафоре - вот [ссылка](https://www.piter.com/collection/all/product/struktury-dannyh-i-algoritmy-v-java-klassika-computers-science-2-e-izd-2#tab-7).

Сам плагин в браузере включен.

Comment: Запускайте с помощью [appletviewer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/appletviewer.html).

Comment: Извиняюсь, забыл упомянуть, запуск апплета и проводил с помощью appletviewer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В современных браузерах поддержка Java апплетов отключена. см. [How do I enable Java in my web browser?](https://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml). Для запуска апплета надо использовать какой-нибудь старый браузер или, как уже советовал @SergeyGornostaev, appletviewer. Вообще, в связи с повсеместным отказом от технологии апплетов, я бы вам рекомендовал пропустить этот раздел в учебнике.

Comment: ", в связи с повсеместным отказом от технологии апплетов, я бы вам рекомендовал пропустить этот раздел в учебнике" +1. И я тоже бы рекомендовал.

Comment: Извиняюсь, забыл упомянуть, запуск апплета и проводил с помощью appletviewer

Comment: Там не раздел, там к каждой главе есть апплет для визуализации разбираемого в этой главе алгоритма.

Comment: Вы можете попробовать использовать более старую версию Java? Какую-нибудь восьмую или даже седьмую? Либо надо попытаться настроить java.policy вашей JDK.

Comment: Игорь, а как это сделать? я не смог найти этот файл(

Comment: см. /Library/Java/Home/lib/security